# Observing particular Port for measuring network game performance

Tags: java, networking, multiplayer, performance, testing

How can I check/inspect the performance of some network application via observing the port it used, I want to test the performance of my network game.

If my game is using port 1009, how can I check the different parameters, like data outflow, inflow and other metrics on this port?

Comment: Use ports above 1024. The low ports are unavailable on most systems, and they're reserved for "well-known" protocols by IANA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest Wireshark (ex Ethereal) as an interesting solution.

- [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org) is free, open source and cross-platform.

I worked with Ethereal (before it changed to Wireshark) in the past, and I must admit that it was a very powerful tool. So WireShark is probably as powerful as Ethereal was and is probably more user friendly than it was in old days.

According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wireshark)

> Wireshark is a free and open-source
>   packet analyzer. It is used for
>   network troubleshooting, analysis,
>   software and communications protocol
>   development, and education. Originally
>   named Ethereal, in May 2006 the
>   project was renamed Wireshark due to
>   trademark issues.
>
> Wireshark is cross-platform, using the
>   GTK+ widget toolkit to implement its
>   user interface, and using pcap to
>   capture packets; it runs on various
>   Unix-like operating systems including
>   Linux, Mac OS X, BSD, and Solaris, and
>   on Microsoft Windows. There is also a
>   terminal-based (non-GUI) version
>   called TShark. Wireshark, and the
>   other programs distributed with it
>   such as TShark, are free software,
>   released under the terms of the GNU
>   General Public License.

Here is a [video introduction](http://wiresharkdownloads.riverbed.com/video/wireshark/introduction-to-wireshark/) to quickly have an idea of the interface and how it can be used and another one [that shows you the ins and outs of advanced graphing](http://www.novell.com/common/flash/play.php?media=http://www.novell.com/recording/videos/connectionmagazine/novell_connection1007.flv).

Finally, here is the [Wireshark User's Guide](http://www.wireshark.org/docs/wsug_html_chunked/).

Comment: I would also recommend tcpdump, but Wireshark might be better because of the UI.

Comment: Although they both use "libpcap" to work, an alternative is always interesting to know of. And as I wasn't aware of it, and because I like command-line tools; thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to check how much data is passed trough that specific port and suming that you are using windows vista or windows 7 you can also use windows resource manager, in network tab there is tcp connections which show you how much data is passed trough specific connection at time you are monitoring, you can also filter connections by process in that tab.